# Regexp showing unexpected Type error in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, typeerror

This is quite bizarre, no idea why it happens, but here it is.
When I do this:

```
/^\d+$/.test('16')
```

it works fine. But when I do something like the following, I get an error

```
var t = /^\d+$/.test;
t('16');
```

The error I get is this:

**TypeError: Method RegExp.prototype.test called on incompatible receiver [object Window]**

I don't know what it has got to do with Window over here....any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do `/^\d+$/.test('16')` you are invoking the `test` function with your regexp as the `this` object (i.e. as a method invocation on an object).

When you run `t(16)` you have no object specified, and so `this` defaults to the top object, which is `window`.

To replicate the first behavior you'd have to do this:

```
var r = /^\d+$/;
var t = r.test;
t.call(r, 16);
```

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a new function that uses the regex as `this`:

```
var r = /^\d+$/;
var t = r.test.bind(r)
t(16)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is the one you want if you are trying to pass a regex test into a callback

Answer (score 0):

I saw this come up when I wanted to filter an array by things matching a regular expression, and fixed it using `bind`:

```
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'A'];
var pattern = new RegExp('^a$', 'i');
var matches = items.filter(pattern.test.bind(pattern));
console.log(matches);
```

Which results as:

```
['a', 'A']
```